# Deleting all channels doesn't work discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a bot that deleting all channels of a Discord server.
Here my code :

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot Ready");
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  console.log(message);
  if (message.content === ".setup") {
    message.guild.channels.forEach((channel) => channel.delete());
  }
});

client.login(
  "token"
);
```

When I launch it and I execute the command, nothing is happening. My bot is Administrator.

Someone can help me please ?

---

Alden Vacker

Comment: Have you enabled to message content intent in your developer portal?

Comment: Why are you trying to make a bot that deletes a server's channels? This sounds like a malicious bot that is trying to impersonate another bot.

Comment: @Elitezen Yes everything is good on the side of the portal developer.

Comment: @HeyHoo I'm discover discord.js and I have some servers where I want delete all channels to restant my Discord servers ;)

Answer (score 1):

It has a very easy fix.
Just put `cache` like this:

```js
 message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => channel.delete());
```